# В чем разница между «данные маршрута» и «данные строки запроса»?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core-mvc

Вот три источника, которые привязчик модели просматривает в поиске значений для параметров метода контроллера:

1. `Request.Form`
2. `RouteData.Values`
3. `Request.Query`

С первым все понятно.

**Я не могу понять разницу между** `RouteData.Values` (данные маршрута) и `Request.Query` (данные строки запроса).

К примеру, на сервер пришел запрос `/api/products?id=123` и если я правильно понимаю, `id=123` попадает в `Request.Query`. А **откуда** и **что** сохраняется в `RouteData.Values`? Разве `api/products` не есть маршрут, а `id=123` его параметры? Т.е. мне казалось, что в `RouteData.Values` и `Request.Query` храниться то же самое.

Comment: зависит от route, например для `api/{param}`,  будет соответствовать адрес `/api/10?id=123`, при разборе, `id=123` будет в `Request.Query`, а `param=10` в `RouteData.Values`